# android.support.v7.cardview:cardBackgroundColor doesn't work

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have the following XML code in a resource file, which represents an item in a RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android.support.v7.cardview="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardBackgroundColor="#9e9e9e"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/field_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:typeface="monospace" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_recyclerview_item_actions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/delete"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is that the CardView is never get the color: 9e9e9e as the following image:
The color is white not 9e9e9e

[image]

Where is the problem in the code? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you try with card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#9e9e9e" without  android.support.v7

Comment: Very good. I have changed it and the card has got the color. Thank you.

Comment: i put an answer you can accept it if im help you , if you want of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove

`android.support.v7`

and set only

`card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#9e9e9e"`

Hope to help!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove cardBackgroundColor attribute and set `android:background="#9e9e9e"` to the first `LinearLayout` in your layout.  I mean this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android.support.v7.cardview="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9e9e9e"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/field_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_recyclerview_item_actions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DELETE"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cv_bgcolor"
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You could modify this code like:

```
android.support.v7.cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@color/myColor"
```

and then go to `Strings.xml` folder and add this line:

```
<color name="myColor">#e9e9e9</color>
```

Comment: Had a similar problem and when I added the color code directly it did not work, used this approach and it solved my problem.

Comment: you did not mean `string.xml` but styles?

Comment: @Vucko I actually meant string.xml

Comment: well you are not supposed to store colors in strings.xml, and also if it's already in the strings, you are not going to get it with `@color/mycolor`